# In python how to print a character before a matching pattern that occur multiple times?

Tags: python, string

I have a stringified data from which I'm trying to print a character that occurs before a matching pattern. This matching pattern will occur multiple times so the result can also be a list of characters

E.g

Stringified data is `[[1, "[{\"name\": \"john\", \"id\": \"1\"}]", [2, "[{\"name\": \"john\", \"id\": \"1\"}]"]`

The matching pattern from the data will be `, "[`

The Expected result is `1 2`

As we can see the charecter `1` and `2` is printed before each occurance of `, "[`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the data you posted is the data you need to process? I'm asking because the number of opening and closing brackets does not match. If this is really the data you have, you should ask whatever source you got that data from to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the input Thomas .. but unfortunately sometimes I have erroneous JSON data so it can fail.

Comment: And then you manually build a Regex for each incorrect JSON you get? Ask the source to provide valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely on the basis of what's asked in the question (and not wondering WHY?) one could do this:

```
astring = '[[1, "[{\"name\": \"john\", \"id\": \"1\"}]", [2, "[{\"name\": \"john\", \"id\": \"1\"}]"]'

pattern = ', "['

offset = 0
pchars = []

while (index := astring[offset:].find(pattern)) >= 0:
    if offset + index > 0:
        pchars.append(astring[offset+index-1])
    offset += index + 1

print(*pchars)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that the data you posted is JSON (because it looks like JSON) and you just made a mistake when posting the data here, because the number of opening and closing brackets does not match.

In that case, please do not use Regex at all. Use JSON instead:

```py
import json
data = '[[1, "[{\\"name\\": \\"john\\", \\"id\\": \\"1\\"}]"], [2, "[{\\"name\\": \\"john\\", \\"id\\": \\"1\\"}]"]]'
parsed = json.loads(data)
for arr in parsed:
    print(arr[0], end=" ")
```

Why? Because JSON can be formatted in different ways. It may be pretty printed, it may have additional spaces. Building a Regex which matches all the possible formats is probably harder that expected.

Comment: Thanks for the input Thomas .. but unfortunately sometimes I have erroneous JSON data so it can fail.